# If $\mathbb F$ is algebrically closed then any polynomial in $\mathbb F[x]$ is a product of linear factors

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have came across this question in my homework and I have no clue what to do or how to start, I just can not connect the dots. If anyone can give me a direction, I'll be very thankful.

> Given an algebrically closed field $\mathbb F$ and $f \in \mathbb F[x]$ whose biggest power is $\geq 0$ so $f$ is a multiplication of linear elements.

Comment: Is it by induction?

Comment: You can do this by induction. Do you know what follows from the fact that $F$ is algebraically closed and $f\in F[x]$ with $\deg f>0$?

Comment: It would help if you told us how you define *algebraically closed*. One of the possible characterisations is the proposition you're having trouble with. By the way, you probably want $\deg f > 0$, since if $\deg f = 0$ there are no linear polynomials which divide $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

(1) if $\,\Bbb A\,$ is an algebracially closed field then any non-constant polynomial $\,p(x)\in\Bbb A[x]\,$ has a root in $\,\Bbb A\,$

2) Over *any* field $\,\Bbb F\,$, an element $\,w\;$ is a root of $\,f(x)\in\Bbb F[x]\,$ iff $\,(x-w)\,\mid\,p(x)\,$ **in** $\,\Bbb F[x]\,$

(3) Induction on $\,\deg \,(p)\,$